# Array com números grandes

Tags: array, c++

Este programa guarda 5 números em array e depois apresenta-os, mas imaginando que quero guardar números grandes como:

*8.12415367228151 / 119.038571952966 / 169.873349402464 / 324.997128488111 / -283.262126034417*

Que modificação posso fazer para que o programa guarde números deste tamanho mas também possa guardar números mais pequenos como:
*20/30/40/-50/-60*

Já exprimentei mudar o `int values[5]` para `long int value [5]` e para outros tipos de data types mas não chego a lado nenhum.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main() {
        int values[5];
        printf("Enter 5 integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            scanf_s(" %d", &values[i]);
        }
        printf("Displaying integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            printf("%d\n", values[i]);
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Consulte <limits> para saber os limites mínimos e máximos dos valores passíveis de serem armazenados no diversos tipos de dados.

Comment: Caso deseje trabalhar com números de precisão arbitrária utilize alguma biblioteca específica, como a GMP - The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library [https://gmplib.org/].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você marcou este código com a tag de C++, porém é visível que está em C.

Fiquei em duvida se este seu exemplo de números grande é um inteiro ou duplo, porém como o array é de int vou assumir que é inteiro.

Variáveis podem guardar qualquer valor, desde que o valor esteja dentro do seu intervalo, então não precisa modificar nada, apenas escolher o tipo correto.

Você disse ter alterado o tipo de int para long int, mas também é preciso alterar as especificações de leitura e escrita de %d para %ld.

Eu fiz aqui um exemplo usando o tipo int64_t definido no cabeçalho stdint.h, este tipo consegue armazenar números muito grandes, e só usei funções presentes na biblioteca padrão do C para manter a portabilidade.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  const int vSize = 5;

  int64_t values[vSize];

  printf("Digite %d números inteiros\n", vSize);

  for(int i = 0; i < vSize; ++i) {
    printf("%d: ", (i + 1));
    scanf("%ld", &values[i]);
  }

  printf("Exibindo os números\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < vSize; ++i) {
    printf("%d: %ld\n", (i + 1), values[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça com `long long int value[]` e `scanf("%lli", value[i]);`

Não sei se estes números que você mostrou são inteiros, porque você colocou um ponto, então se não forem coloque um `long double`